# Why do I have to use binding redirects in XUnit specs when the project file has AutoGenerateBindingRedirects set to true

Tags: f#, msbuild, xunit.net, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an [XUnit](https://xunit.github.io/) based spec project written in F#. It has **[AutoGenerateBindingRedirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx)** set to **true** as in

```
 <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

However to get the specs running in the VS2017 test runner I need to add an app.config with binding redirects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.1.0" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Does AutoGenerateBindingRedirects actually do anything in this case? If not then what is it's purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

You need both of them for unit test projects.

Comment: Why only for unit test projects ? What is the reason ?